# JSTL Condition check doesn't work when an OR condition is put in EL

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jstl

I have a map, and it's declared as field inside an object, something like below

```
public class FunctionUtilities{

        protected Map ResourceAccessabilityMap=new HashMap();

    }
```

The object is set in session in a controller when the user logs in to my application.

```
public class LoginController{
    public String login(HttpServletRequest request, @ModelAttribute(“loginData) LoginData loginData){

        session.setAttribute(“utilities”, new FunctionUtilities().loadFunctionUtilities(loginData));
    }

  }
```

when a request comes in or the user logs in to be precise, there're two values set in the map conditionally like this,

```
public class FunctionUtilities{

        protected Map ResourceAccessabilityMap=new HashMap();

    public Map loadFunctionUtilities(LoginData loginData){

        if(loginData.hasAccessToStudentData)
            ResourceAccessabilityMap.put(“STUDENT_DATA”, “TRUE”);


        if(loginData.hasAccessToLecturerData)
            ResourceAccessabilityMap.put(“LECTURER_DATA”, “TRUE”);
    }

    }
```

The above information is used to display different sidebar navigation links according to the users’ access.

There's a situation when both the conditions are failing as expected so the map doesn't have the values STUDENT_DATA or LECTURER_DATA.

when I'm trying to access these values from the included jsp page for sidebar navigation using JSTL in an if condition, both of them are evaluating to true. My sidebar navigation JSP is something like below,

sidebar.jsp

```
<%@ include file="../../view/include/jstl.jsp" %>
    <c:if test="${not empty utilities['STUDENT_DATA'] || not empty utilities['LECTURER_DATA']}" >
    Display user's account balance
    </c:if>
```

As an output it displays user's account balance which is not what I would expect right?

but when I remove one of the conditions

```
<%@ include file="../../view/include/jstl.jsp" %>
<c:if test="${not empty utilities['STUDENT_DATA']}" >
Display user's account balance
</c:if>
```

It works fine and doesn't display the user's account balance

My jstl.jsp is just a custom jsp which looks like this

```
<%@ page session="false"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>
```

The sidebar.jsp page is included in the actual page

myaccount.jsp

```
<%@ include file=“/navigation/sidebar.jsp” %>
```

Need some help as I'm going crazy over how can the condition evaluate differently when placed individually but doesn't work when put together

Comment: post the jsp code where you are using JSTL

Comment: I have added the code snippet from the sidebar.jsp page which has the jstl if condition check there. Did you mean you wanted the entire jsp page?

Comment: I simulated you code and it work fine for me ! if utilities['STUDENT_DATA'] or utilities['LECTURER_DATA'] are not empty -> Display user's account balance else do not display

Comment: and correct the loadFunctionUtilities function : missing return statement

Comment: yeah missed to copy the return statement there. Thanks for your response though. I have done the same thing thousands of times but never faced an issue quite like this. May be am missing something. Let me cross check if I have missed to share any information in this forum.